# Тестирование метода с обьектом класса в параметрах java

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Написал простой калькулятор на Спринге. Вопрос - как правильно тестировать service методы? Model класс

```
public class Operation {


    private Long Id;
    private double first;
    private double second;
    private String operation;
    private String result; 
//геттеры, сеттеры, конструкторы
```

Сервис класс (для примера один метод)

```
@Service
public class CalculateService {
    
    public double add(Operation model) {
        return model.getFirst() + model.getSecond();

    }
```

Я понимаю, как протестировать, если в параметры метода add придут два значения, но как тестировать, если приходит обьект класса?
p.s. если кто может подсказать хорошую литературу для тестирования java/spring - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: а в чем разница между 2 значениями и объектом? Что вас смущает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тесте будет что-то похожее:

```
@Test
public void testAdd() {
    Operation op = new Operation(1.0, 2.0);
    double result = calculateService.add(op);
    assertEquals(3.0, result);
}
```

И, как сказали выше в комментарии, особой разницы нет в том, что вам придет 2 параметра или объект с двумя параметрами.

Comment: спасибо, я только начал изучение тестов и для меня пока что все в новинку